# Is it correct to say "don't drink old water, drink new one"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is [an article](https://www.thelist.com/187362/what-happens-to-your-body-when-you-drink-old-water/#:%7E:text=Old%20water%20contains%20bacteria%2C%20but%20it%27s%20generally%20yours&text=%22If%20it%27s%20allowed%20to%20incubate,and%20then%20throwing%20it%20away.) "**Old water contains bacteria, but it's generally yours**", which could be written by native speakers

Can we say "**old water**" to refer to water left overnight in **an open container** or in **a close container** but you put your mouth or your tongue in the water. In both cases, bacterium may spread the whole water?

and

Can we say "**new water**" to refer to water left overnight in **a closed container** and has not been infected from your mouth or tongue?

Comment: As far as I know, _old water_ is not a standard phrase. The people quoted in the article explain what they mean by it. You can't say "Drink new one" in this context; you would have to say "Drink fresh water", "Use a new bottle", or "Replace it with fresh [water]". (Of course, _fresh water_ can also mean _not seawater_, but the meaning should be obvious from the context.)

Answer (score 6):

The word “old” wouldn’t normally be used in this kind of context. The more specific English word that is used to describe a food or drink that may have had its edibility or potability compromised by the passage of time is “stale”.

Comment: And the antonym of stale is "fresh".